# How can show and stop the execution when several codebuild are completed in bash?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, scripting, aws-codebuild

I am creating a script that starts several builds in AWS Codebuild. In addition to running it, I would like that when each build completes (reaches the COMPLETED phase) and reads the string "COMPLETED", it stops.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Deploy the Layers

BUILD_PROJECT=$1
ENVIRONMENT=$2

if [ -z "$BUILD_PROJECT" ]
then
    echo "BUILD_PROJECT is empty, exiting...."
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$ENVIRONMENT" ]
then
    echo "ENVIRONMENT is empty, exiting...."
    exit 1
fi

# Takes the final phase of codebuild deployment, which is COMPLETED
function getStatus {
    for ids in $BUILD_PROJECT
    do            
        id=$(aws codebuild list-builds-for-project --project-name "${ids}-${ENVIRONMENT}" | jq -r '.ids[0]')
        aws codebuild batch-get-builds --ids "$id" | jq -r '.builds[].phases[] | select (.phaseType=="COMPLETED") | .phaseType'
    done
}

for project in $BUILD_PROJECT
do
    echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Deploying: ${project}-${ENVIRONMENT}"
    echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    aws codebuild start-build --project-name "${project}-${ENVIRONMENT}"

    while [[ $(getStatus) != "COMPLETED" ]]
    do
        if [[ $(getStatus) == "COMPLETED" ]]
        then
            echo $(getStatus)
            exit 0
        else
            echo "Deploying ${project}-${ENVIRONMENT}..."
            getStatus
        fi
    done 
done
```

I would like to see as output something like:

```
----------------------------------------------------
Deploying: lambda1-us2-stage
----------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------
Deploying: lambda2-us2-stage
----------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------
Deploying: lambda3-us2-stage
----------------------------------------------------
Deploying lambda1-us2-stage...
Deploying lambda2-us2-stage...
Deploying lambda3-us2-stage...
Deploying lambda1-us2-stage...
Deploying lambda2-us2-stage...
Deploying lambda3-us2-stage...
lambda1-us2-stage COMPLETED
lambda2-us2-stage COMPLETED
lambda3-us2-stage COMPLETED
```

And after all 3 are finished, end the script.

The current output is:

```
----------------------------------------------------
Deploying: lambda1-us2-stage
----------------------------------------------------
Deploying lambda1-us2-stage...
COMPLETED
COMPLETED
Deploying lambda1-us2-stage...
COMPLETED
COMPLETED
Deploying lambda1-us2-stage...
COMPLETED
COMPLETED
Deploying lambda1-us2-stage...
COMPLETED
COMPLETED
```

And so it iterates to infinity and only 1 lambda is deployed, the others are not.

Comment: Ok, so what does your current code show as output?

Comment: @Nic3500 Done! Edited with the current output. Thanks!

Comment: You start multiple builds.  Than run getStatus.  That getStatus should return COMPLETED on each instance that is done, or only once they are all done?  There is a code logic weirdness here.  You check the return value of getStatus, which could be a mix of completed and still running builds.  You need to work on getStatus IMHO, to support multiple instances and process status output information from multiple instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this adding a new function showStatus and converting the getStatus into an array. This way:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Deploy the Layers and Lambdas

BUILD_PROJECT=$1
ENVIRONMENT=$2

if [ -z "$BUILD_PROJECT" ]
then
    echo "BUILD_PROJECT is empty, exiting...."
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$ENVIRONMENT" ]
then
    echo "ENVIRONMENT is empty, exiting...."
    exit 1
fi

# Takes the final phase of every codebuild deployment, which is COMPLETED
function getStatus {   
    for ids in $BUILD_PROJECT
    do  
        id=$(aws codebuild list-builds-for-project --project-name "${ids}-${ENVIRONMENT}" | jq -r '.ids[0]')
        aws codebuild batch-get-builds --ids "$id" | jq -r '.builds[].phases[] | select (.phaseType=="COMPLETED") | .phaseType'
    done
}

# Check if the deployment is finished and print COMPLETED, if not, print a progress until COMPLETED
function showStatus {
    while [[ ${#PROJECT_STATUS[@]} != ${#COUNT_PROJECT[@]} ]]
    do
        PROJECT_STATUS=($(getStatus))
        COUNT_PROJECT=($BUILD_PROJECT)

        if [[ ${#PROJECT_STATUS[@]} == ${#COUNT_PROJECT[@]} ]]
        then
            #This will display something like: Completed... 4/4 - And it will display the final status for each lambda, taken from .phaseType
            echo "Completed ${#PROJECT_STATUS[@]}/${#COUNT_PROJECT[@]}"
            echo $(getStatus)
            exit 0
        else
            #This will display something like: Deploying... 1/4
            echo "Deploying... Completed ${#PROJECT_STATUS[@]}/${#COUNT_PROJECT[@]}"
        fi
    done
}

# This will show which build is running and start the build
for project in $BUILD_PROJECT
do
    echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Deploying: ${project}-${ENVIRONMENT}"
    echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    aws codebuild start-build --project-name "${project}-${ENVIRONMENT}"
done

PROJECT_STATUS=($(getStatus))
COUNT_PROJECT=($BUILD_PROJECT)

showStatus
```